# Воспроизводить онлайн-трансляцию у себя на сайте

Tags: jquery, html, видео, javascript, php

Добрый день! Как решить следующий вопрос?

Я хочу транслировать одно видео со своего экрана через программу xplit. Как все это добро запихнуть на сайт, чтобы можно было транслировать у себя на сайте, а не через сторонние сервисы (twitch, youtube).

С чего начать, где рыть?

Спасибо!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если это именно видео- , а не геймкастер, то я бы вместо xplit посоветовал бы VLC. Там раздача делается просто, и безо всяких сторонних сервисов.